# pycharm can connect wsl by ssh but cant use python in wsl

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want use the python on wsl in pycharm
I refer to this article 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#prereq

pycharm can connect wsl by ssh，but Failed
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ni1.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the interpreter you are trying to use is not installed in your WSL, or you are pointing the wrong place. Make sure it exists, if not try to use /usr/bin/python as the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I use miniconda and have python 3.6 installed on /home/USERNAME/miniconda/. In pycharm, I point the interpreter to /home/USERNAME/miniconda/bin/python3.6.

For different conda envs, point the interpreter to their respective python